# Reduce data in sql table by averaging?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a table with lots of data in sqlite table, which I would like to average and reduce once in a while to keep queries fast. The table just has several measurement data I use for estimating some error co-efficients (table always gets updated).

How can I average data in sqlite with a certain precision or range or area of averaging blocks?

Here is what I have so far, however, it simply depends on the precision of data in column by which I try to group by (column DistanceX).

```
SELECT avg(ErrorX), ErrorType FROM historyIMU WHERE ErrorType='XY' 
GROUP BY DistanceX
```

I want to do something like `GROUP BY DistanceX between +/- 0.05*DistanceX` or some other way of converting thousands of points into few hundreds that still keep the same outline (relationship between DistanceX and ErrorX from my example).

Comment: I just round ROUND function in SQLite. It seems to work good for now, unless someone else would post something better.
`SELECT avg(ErrorX), ErrorType FROM historyIMU WHERE ErrorType='XY' 
GROUP BY ROUND(DistanceX,2)`

Comment: The only problem with above is that I loose more data on lower DistanceX (with value below 1)

Answer (score 0):

I am answering this in very generic sql sense - Instead of `GROUP BY` use `HAVING` clause for filtering X `between 0.95*DistanceX and 1.05*DistanceX`.

But it would be heavy query. Creating index to handle it would improve it slightly but this logic is bound to be heavy.